# accessing member of structure within a class

Tags: c++, class, pointers, struct, structure

I have an .hpp and .cpp file. I want to access the variable in the structure within a class which happens to be in the header .hpp file, in the .cpp file.

In .hpp, I have

```
class foo{

public:
       struct packet{
         int x;
         u_int y;
      };

};

 foo(const char*name)
:m_name(name){}
```

In .cpp I did:

```
foo *foo_1 = &foo;
printf("The value of x is : %d",foo_1->packet.x);
printf ("The value of y is : %u", foo_1->packet.y);
```

On doing this I receive the following error:

```
code_1.cpp:117: error: expected primary-expression before ‘;’ token
code_1.cpp:118: error: invalid use of ‘struct foo::packet’
code_1.cpp:119: error: invalid use of ‘struct foo::packet’
make: *** [code_1] Error 1
```

My objective is to get the values of x and y in the cpp file. Any suggestion/idea will be really appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need a **member object** of type `foo::packet` in `class foo`.

```
class foo{

public:
      struct packet{
         int x;
         u_int y;
      };

      packet my_packet;   // <- THIS
};
```

In your .cpp, you should do:

```
foo *foo_1 = &foo;
printf("The value of x is : %d",foo_1->my_packet.x);
printf ("The value of y is : %u", foo_1->my_packet.y);
```

You must remember that even though `packet` is inside `foo`, it is not included in `foo` as a member object. It is just a class enclosed inside another class. And for a class to be used, you must have objects of it (a class can also be used without having objects of it, but, well...).

Comment: Throws me error:

      code_1.cpp:117: error: no matching function for call to ‘foo::foo()’
      code.hpp:170: note: candidates are: foo::foo(const char*)
      code.hpp:159: note: foo::foo(const foo&)
      make: *** [code_1] Error 1

Comment: @learning That's a problem with your constructor and, with due respect, is out of the scope of your question. Sorry.

Comment: Not a problem. Thanks for the help. Below comment says its a bad idea to declaring a pointer and point it to the address of a class. Will it be a problem, assigining foo_1, address of foo.

Comment: @learning You'll face many problems with pointers. My advice? Minimize their use. Just do `foo myFoo;` and you'll never have to deal with the intricacies of pointers.

Comment: @Mark Garcia: That is until he tries to return a pointer to a temporary variable that has just happened to cease to exist as the function returns :/

Answer (score 3):

In your class `Foo`, you have defined a `packet` struct, but you have not declared any instances of it. What you want is (this is a compileable self-contained example):

```
#include <iostream>

class Foo {
public:
  struct Packet{
    Packet() : x(0), y(0) {}
    int x;
    int y;
  } packet;
};

int main(int, char**)
{
  Foo foo_1;
  std::cout << "The value of x is: " << foo_1.packet.x << std::endl;
  std::cout << "The value of y is: " << foo_1.packet.y << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`packet` is not a data member of the class, but the class that it defines it *is* however. You need to instantiate an object of that type in order to use it in that way:

```
class foo
{
public:
       foo() {} // A default constructor is also needed
       struct
       {
         int x;
         u_int y;
      } packet;
}; // -- don't forget that semicolon

int main()
{
    foo *foo_1 = new foo(); // instantiate a new object on the heap
    printf("The value of x is : %d",foo_1->packet.x);
    printf("The value of y is : %u", foo_1->packet.y);

    delete foo_1; // release the memory
}
```

Comment: Due to constructr signature, I receive error as:
error: no matching function for call to ‘foo::foo()’
code.hpp:170: note: candidates are: foo::foo(const char*)
code.hpp:159: note:                 foo::foo(const foo&)

Any idea how I can resolve this error?

Comment: @learning Sorry about that. You need to add a default constructor to your class: `foo() {}`. I'll update my post with the code.

Answer (score 0):

You have just defined struct. 
Try something like this -

`struct packet{

         int x;

         u_int y;

      }test;`

and in your cpp, access your struct elements like this -
`foo_1.test.x`

Answer (score 0):

The `struct` declaration in the class does not create an instance of it - just defines it as a contained struct within `foo`.
If you create a struct instance in the class, you can reference it from the containing pointer:

```
   struct packet{
     int x;
     u_int y;
  } m_packet;
```

Now you can say `foo_1->m_packet.x = 3;`, etc.

Also, you need to create an instance of foo (in your code you try to take the address of the class name, which won't work):
`foo* foo_1 = new foo;`

Then, `delete foo_1` when done with it.

Answer (score 0):

Class foo does not have a member packet but it contains another class/struct type named "packet".
You'll have to provide a member of that type.

Can't do a test atm but you could either try

```
class foo{

public:
       struct {
         int x;
         u_int y;
      } packet;

}
```

or

```
class foo{
public:
      pack packet;
      struct pack {
         int x;
         u_int y;
      };

}
```

To access x and y via `foo_ptr->packet.(...)` or `foo_object.packet.(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

and besides tha packet-related business, `foo *foo_1 = &foo;` is bad, you can't take address of a class only of a variable.

Answer (score 0):

In .hpp you need to declare a variable with the struct type.
For example,

```
packet Packet;
```

inside of your class

In .cpp, try this

```
foo *foo_ptr = new foo; // creating new foo object in the heap memory with a pointer  foo_ptr
printf("The value of x is : %d",foo_ptr->Packet.x);
printf ("The value of y is : %u", foo_ptr->Packet.y);
```

Answer (score 0):

You declare the struct, but you never put any data in it.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
struct Vehicle
    {
    int wheels;
    char vname[20];
    char color[10];
}v1 = {4,"Nano","Red"};

int main()
{
printf("Vehicle No of Wheels : %d",v1.wheels);
printf("Vehicle Name           : %s",v1.vname);
printf("Vehicle Color          : %s",v1.color);
return(0);
}
```

hope this may help you
we gave the structure name as V1 and acessing the elements by the use of dot operator